# Rails 4.2.1 Reviews logging correctly, but not displaying on show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Working on a movie review app as I learn Rails. Earlier, I noticed that there were four movie reviews that were appearing on all the pages, but no new ones were showing up. I looked in the console and discovered that those four reviews weren't attached to a movie_id (e.g. each was movie_id: nil). So using the rails console, I updated those four reviews to attach them to a particular movie_id.

Now all of the movies are showing "No reviews just yet. Be the first to write one!" even though some of the movies do, in fact, have reviews associated with them (verified with movie_id in rails console).

When I add reviews for a particular movie, the reviews log correctly, as I can see in the rails console:

```
<Review id: 13, rating: 3, comment: "Testing code to see if this review shows up.", created_at: "2015-05-26 21:57:52", updated_at: "2015-05-26 21:57:52", user_id: 1, movie_id: 2>
```

However, the movie display pages still show "No reviews just yet. Be the first to write one!" on the show.html.erb page:

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <%= image_tag @movie.image.url(:medium) %>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Title:</strong></td>
                <td><%= @movie.title %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Description:</strong></td>
                <td><%= @movie.description %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Movie length:</strong></td>
                <td><%= @movie.movie_length %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Director:</strong></td>
                <td><%= @movie.director %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Rating:</strong></td>
                <td><%= @movie.rating %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Average User Rating:</strong></td>
                <td><div class="star-rating" data-score= <%= @avg_rating %> ></div><p><%= "#{@reviews.length} reviews" %></p></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <%= link_to "Write a Review", new_movie_review_path(@movie), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
        <h1 class="review_title"><%= @movie.title %></h1>
        <p><%= @movie.description %></p>

        <% if @reviews.blank? %>
          <h3>No reviews just yet. Be the first to write one!</h3>
          <%= link_to "Write Review", new_movie_review_path(@movie), class: "btn btn-danger" %>
        <% else %>
          <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
            <div class="reviews">
              <div class="star-rating" data-score= <%= review.rating %> ></div>
               <p><%= h(review.comment).gsub(/\n/, '<br/>').html_safe %></p>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_movie_path(@movie) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', movies_path %>

<script>
    $('.star-rating').raty({
      path: '/assets/',
      readOnly: true,
      score: function() {
            return $(this).attr('data-score');
    }
  });
</script>
```

I think it's all defined correctly in the movies_controller:

```
 class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_movie, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  # GET /movies
  # GET /movies.json
  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
  end

  def search
    if params[:search].present?
      @movies = Movie.search(params[:search])
    else
      @movies = Movie.all
    end
  end

  # GET /movies/1
  # GET /movies/1.json
  def show
    @reviews = Review.where(movie_id: @movie_id).order("created_at DESC")
    if @reviews.blank?
      @avg_rating = 0
    else
      @avg_rating = @reviews.average(:rating).round(2)
    end
  end

  # GET /movies/new
  def new
    @movie = current_user.movies.build
  end

  # GET /movies/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /movies
  # POST /movies.json
  def create
    @movie = current_user.movies.build(movie_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @movie.save
        format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @movie }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /movies/1
  # PATCH/PUT /movies/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @movie.update(movie_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @movie }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /movies/1
  # DELETE /movies/1.json
  def destroy
    @movie.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to movies_url, notice: 'Movie was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_movie
      @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def movie_params
      params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :description, :movie_length, :director, :rating, :image)
    end
end
```

And here's my reviews_controller as well:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_movie
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /reviews/new
  def new
    @review = Review.new
  end

  # GET /reviews/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /reviews
  # POST /reviews.json
  def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.user_id = current_user.id 
    @review.movie_id = @movie.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @review.save
        format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Review was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @review }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /reviews/1
  # PATCH/PUT /reviews/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @review.update(review_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Review was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @review }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /reviews/1
  # DELETE /reviews/1.json
  def destroy
    @review.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Review was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_review
      @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_movie
      @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :comment)
    end
end
```

I just can't quite see what I'm missing here. Can anyone see why the reviews are logging accurately and showing up in the console, but not showing up on the movie page?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reviews are not loading because you have a typo in the show action:

```
@reviews = Review.where(movie_id: @movie_id).order("created_at DESC")
```

That should be:

```
@reviews = Review.where(movie_id: @movie.id).order("created_at DESC")
```

This is because you've set the @movie variable, but not a @movie_id variable.